# SQL Server: String or Binary Would be Truncated ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

So I've been working on a page to allow users to submit content, and everything on the page seems to work but when it comes to communicating with the SQL server an error keeps getting thrown.
The error says that the process has been terminated since the string or binary would be truncated.
[image: The error I am receiving.]

Here is the code I am using to handle the communications with the server.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\Will\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\inshort\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF"";Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO aspnet_newscontent (author, username, date, category, content, description) VALUES (@author, @username, @date, @category, @content, @description)");
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                if (nameInput.Text != "")
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", nameInput.Text);
                }
                else if (nameInput.Text == "")
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", "Anonymous");
                }
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Today);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", categoryId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", content.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description.Text);
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: Your text column's length is shorter than the text you're inserting. What is your table scheme?

Comment: I think you should set content and  description columns length to max

Comment: try putting a breakpoint and check which values you are putting higher than the range what you defined in the `SQL table`. Also try inserting data from the SQL and check whether it is getting inserted properly or not, or at _which_ column it is showing more than expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused when trying to insert values in a column greater than the max size of the column specified.

See [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1734911.aspx?String%20or%20binary%20data%20would%20be%20truncated)